# git: What if a second branch tracks another branch in origin?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-track

What are the consequences of having a remote branch with the same origin as another one?

For example

```
   // Create branch foo but track origin/bar instead of origin/foo
   git branch --track foo origin/bar
   git push origin foo
```

What are the side effects of such links?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't cause any side effect. It is just the name you have given to your local branch.

But depending on your config, you will have to do:

```
git push origin foo:bar
```

otherwise it will create a new branch ( or push to a branch) of name foo

Alternatively, add the following to .git/config:

```
[push]
    default = tracking
```

or do `git config push.default tracking`